# How to spawn mobs still

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-education-edition

In Minecraft, I have seen videos in which mobs are completely still, not even budging a pixel when attacked.

I think this is possible via commands

How do I do this?

Answer (score -1):

Use the data value NoAI:1 to keep a mob from moving by itself. For example, the following command will summon a Zombie that will not move by itself.

```
/summon zombie ~ ~1 ~ {NoAI:1}
```

Generated from [digminecraft.com](https://www.digminecraft.com/generators/summon_mob.php).

*Note: this was a Java Edition command. I have no idea if it will work in Education Edition. I do hope it does, I suggest you try it and find out. Let me know if it doesn't work.*

Comment: bedrock only supports spawn event

Comment: I know (from the Minecraft wiki). However, I saw on my server host that education edition is an option, so I didn't know if it applied to Java Edition.